# git-svn...more like snail mail

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Today at work I needed to clone a certain project with git-svn due to certain constraints and the command I used to do that is `git svn clone -T --no-minimize-url URL_OF_THE_REPO`. Long story short... this has been PAINFULLY SLOW, and also keeps failing reliably because of some error in git... which naturally makes me continue the cloning by restarting the command, I can't just leave it and know it will complete the clone job when I come back. So making it a night job is out of the question.

1. Why in the name of god is it so slow,
2. How can I speed the (checkout) process,
3. How can I planify night-jobs to do these heavy clone jobs and be confident they would have completed in the morning(I reiterate, I have to keep a watchful eye over the checkout in case it fails)

Comment: Not sure if this help you but in the past I have used something like (svn export GIT_REPO_URL  DIRECTORY_PATH_TO_LOCAL_LOCATION) and I didn't have any issues with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 I think it's because svn was not designed to work the way git works (with objects that are fetched that are compressed and sent in a single block). git-svn has to go revision by revision to replicate the content of the svn branches/tags into git equivalents.

2 and 3 are related: You can try asking for the fetch process to start from a revision that you know has already been retrieved so that git-svn doesn't have to start from scratch each time. you can do something like `git svn fetch -r 10000:HEAD`.

Comment: I don't know why my question and your answers are getting hate, your answer seems legit.

Comment: Although I can't say it is the deffinite explanation :) I'll give it a couple of days before I validate it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

> Why in the name of god is it so slow,

Because in Git you always clone a full repository, not only one commit. This means, to do a full `git-svn` clone, `git-svn` has to download each and every SVN revision individually and transform it to a Git commit. This simply needs time. This is one of the reasons why I discourage everyone to use `git-svn` for one-time migrations but only recommend `git-svn` as frontend to SVN where you need to commit back to the SVN server from the Git clone, which is what `git-svn` was created for.

> How can I speed the (checkout) process,

The checkout process is fast. I guess you mean the clone / fetch process. Well there are only two things you could do when using `git-svn`.

1. Do the cloning / fetchin on the SVN server machine if possible, this way you spare the protocol overhead and network latency. But make sure to use the right combination of parameters, so that you end up with the remote SVN URL in the commit message metadata, otherwise you will have problems updating / dcommitting later from your workstation.
2. Do a "shallow" clone. You can tell `git-svn` which revisions to fetch. So if you are not interested in the full history in your `git-svn` clone, tell the clone command from which revision to start. If you e. g. only fetch the last 5 commits, you need just some seconds to finish.

> How can I planify night-jobs to do these heavy checkouts and be confident they would have completed in the morning(I reiterate, I have to keep a watchful eye over the checkout in case it fails)

Once the clone command started to actually fetch the SVN revisions, you should be able to resume the process by using `git svn fetch`. So just do `git svn fetch` in a loop until the clone is finished, **if** it gets finished. I write *if*, because it could hit a bug in `git-svn` or some incompatibility like stangely named branches or tags that can make the process fail reliably at the same revision. In that case you have to handle it manually of course, as resuming will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could init (not fully clone) the repo empty.

The  edit the repo .git/config to filter the branches and tag to fetch.

Then fetch.

Comment: But I need all the files in the branch. How is fetching going to be different?

Comment: *First* checkout is slow, update fetches are *normal*. what I propose is to fetch only some branches, not all, as git svn re-slurp from rev_1 for each branch or tag. Don't worry about getting all the files from a branch. Just curious : how many revision this svn held ?